# SQL Server job to use external Powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, powershell

I have a SQL Server job which runs some Powershell code, but although when running the Powershell script in a PS editor on the machine it runs successfully, when running the SQL Agent Job with the same code it fails.

And the reason it fails is because it doesn't manage to add a few snap-ins, like the one below or include some assemblies.

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
```

This leads me to believe that SQL Server has a internal version of Powershell installed with which it runs the Powershell jobs. And that specific internal version of Powershell is older and does not have the required assemblies / snap-ins and thus fails.

Now, is there any way I can use the Powershell version installed on my machine and not the one that's built into SQL Server?

I've looked over "Proxies" in SQL Server but I don't think they're what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are correct, SQL uses an internal version of powershell.  You will need to use a command line job step and run the powershell.exe and point to the .ps1 file you want to execute.  Make sure to set your execution policy correctly.

Comment: Why not use the scheduler in Windows instead of using SQL Server Agent to do operating system stuff?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'd prefer to and also suggested to use the Windows scheduler, but it's a... `"requirement"`, which is sometimes harder to fight than magically building a solution.

Comment: @JonathanFite I know I might be asking for too much, but is there a example on how to do this? There are a lot of new words for me in your sentence, like `"policy"`, `"command line job step"`.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, You want to use a SQL Agent job, but specify a cmdexec job step.  Then the command is going to be "Powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\scripts\script.ps1".  Where you have saved the powershell script you want to run in "C:\scripts\script.ps1".    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx

Comment: @JonathanFite, consider posting your cmdexec solution as an answer along with a job create script example.

Comment: @JonathanFite Please post your solution as an answer. It did solve my problem and I would like to officially "reward you" and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is an example of the process.  The step should look like this, though

**Job Step Command**
Set the step to be a cmdexec job and then run powershell through that.  It lets you use the latest version of powershell as well as configure the powershell environment for that user (if you want).  The step command will look like the one below, complete with arguments for the example.  Remember to put quotes around strings that contain spaces.

Powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\Scripts\DailyRestoreScript.ps1" -Arguments -SourceSQLInstance 'localhost\jdf2016' -SourceDatabaseName 'AdventureWorks' -TargetSQLInstance 'localhost\jdf2016' -TargetDatabaseName 'AdventureWorks2'

**Complete Job**

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [DailyRestore_ADWorks]    Script Date: 2/16/2017 9:00:51 AM ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 2/16/2017 9:00:51 AM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'DailyRestore_ADWorks', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Daily restore AD Works from backup', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name='XXXXX\JFite', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Restore ADWorks]    Script Date: 2/16/2017 9:00:51 AM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Restore ADWorks', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
        @command=N'Powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\Scripts\DailyRestoreScript.ps1" -Arguments -SourceSQLInstance ''localhost\jdf2016'' -SourceDatabaseName ''AdventureWorks'' -TargetSQLInstance ''localhost\jdf2016'' -TargetDatabaseName ''AdventureWorks2''', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Comment: Wow, this is way more than I expected! Excelent! I was using the interface from SSMS, but this is much better. Thank you once again!

Comment: and thanks for the prompting to finally make this a real answer.