# SQL Agent PowerShell job runs in ISE but not in SQL Servere

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell

My PowerShell script uses WinSCP to download files.  It writes a message to a sql server table containing the number of files downloaded.  When run within ISE it's fine.  When run as a sql agent job it fails with error msg 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.'  This error is generated by the variable that the file count is assigned to.  The variable is $fileCount.

The code is below.  See variable `$fileCount`.  I suspect that the beginning `$` in the variable name is causing sql to misinterpret the variable in some way but I'm not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

```sh
# Step 1 - Powershell script to download xml files to local folder.


param (
    $remotepath = "./",
    $mask = "*.xml",
    $destination = "D:\Files\Downloaded"
)




try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET Assembly
    Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll" 


    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "hostname"
        UserName = "user"
        Password = 'password'  
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "fingerprint"
    }


    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    $fileCount = 0
    $elements = 0
    $errOut = $null

    try
    {
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
        $directory = $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles($remotepath, $mask, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::None)
        $elements = $directory.count
        **$fileCount = $elements.count**

        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
        $transferResult = $session.GetFiles($remotepath, $destination, $False, $transferOptions)
        $transferResult.Check()
     } # end try


    finally
    {
        $session.Dispose()
    }

} # end try

catch
{
        $errOut = ($_.Exception.Message)
}


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString;"
$SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC Stored_Proc @chvMessage, @chvFileIndex, @chvRecordCount"
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@chvMessage", [system.data.SqlDbType]::nvarchar) | Out-Null
$SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvMessage'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@chvFileIndex", [system.data.SqlDbType]::nvarchar) | Out-Null
$SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvFileIndex'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@chvRecordCount", [system.data.SqlDbType]::nvarchar) | Out-Null
$SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvRecordCount'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input


$SqlConnection.Open()
if ($errOut -ne $null)
{
    $SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvMessage'].Value = $errOut
}

if ($errOut -eq $null)
{
    $SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvMessage'].Value =  "**** " + $fileCount.toString() + " FILES DOWNLOADED"
}


$SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvFileIndex'].Value = ''

$SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvRecordCount'].Value = ""
$SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: The powershell engine that runs as a job step is not the same as the one that runs from the ISE.  My advice is to save this as a .ps1 file on the server and then invoke it as a straight cmd job step.  See my answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148317/sql-server-job-to-use-external-powershell/164547#164547 for details.

Comment: But you code seems strange anyway. You are effectively calling `$directory.count.count` - What do you expect this to do?

Comment: I found that $directory.count returns a list, $directory.count.count returns the number of files.

Comment: OK, anyway, did you try to find out what statement throws the exception - and consequently, what object is null?

Comment: This the statement that throws the exception because $fileCount is null.  The mystery to me is why it is never set.  This doesn't occur in ISE.  $SqlCommand.Parameters['@chvMessage'].Value =  "**** " + $fileCount.toString() + " FILES DOWNLOADED"

Comment: Try `($directory | measure).Count`

Comment: Did you try it?